# Replacing a column of an output with another name and saving it as .CSV file

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I have an output with two columns and I want to replace one of the columns with a string and save it as a .csv file.

For example, the text file:

```
year, user, tweet
2009, Katie, I love playing football
2010, James, I play football
2013, Bob, I play basketball
2013, James, I play Baseball
```

The delimiter is ',' and there are 3 tweets with the exact word 'play' and 2 of them are from 2013 and 1 in 2010. Replacing `2013` with `Development` and `2011` with `Early`.

The output should be:

```
Early, 1
Development, 2
```

Then save to a new .csv file

I have only been able to do this so far:

```
$ awk -F, '{IGNORECASE=1} {ARGC=1} /\<play\>/{a[$1]++} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' Tweet.txt | sort
```

output :

```
2010 1
2013 2
```

I have just started learning BASH and would greatly appreciate some help :)

WITH SED

if my original output was like this

```
2010 1
2013 2010
```

Meaning that for year 2013, the number of times "play" came up was 2013 times, with `sed -e 's/2010/Early/' -e 's/2013/Development/'` The output will be:

```
Early 1
Development Early
```

Would you mind helping me out further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk  -F, '$1=="2013" && /play/ {$1="Development"; play++; dev=$1 FS" " play} $1=="2010" && /play/ {$1="Early"; play1++; early=$1 FS" " play1} NR > 1 && NF == 2; END { print early"\n" dev > "twitter.csv" }' input_file
```

```
$ cat replace.awk

BEGIN {
    FS=","                                        #Set the field seperator to comma
} $1=="2013" && /play/ {                          #If column1 is 2013 and any column matches play
    $1="Development"; play++; dev=$1 FS" " play   #Change column1, count play and create variable
} $1=="2010" && /play/ {                          #Same as above 
    $1="Early"; play1++; early=$1 FS" " play1   
} NR > 1 && NF == 2 
END { 
    print early"\n" dev  > "twitter.csv"          #Print variables seperated by new line
}
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -f replace.awk input_file
Early, 1
Development, 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This works perfectly :) If you don't mind, could you please clarify some doubts for me? So what does the ++ and FS play do? does it count and then output the number of times play occurs in the line? Is there a way to make the output have a space, for example; Early, 1 --> With space after comma. Lastly, how would I convert this into .csv file named "twitter.csv" for example?
Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Mateybro `FS` is the field seperator in this case comma `,` so we can seperate the colums. `++` increments/counts the matches in this case the word `play`. It will show the count for each line that matched hence the `END` to output the final result. Regarding the final requests, I will update the answer to include a space and output to twitter.scv

Comment: ohh right, I see what you did there now. Thank you so much! I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 2):

pipe this `sed` to your attempt

`sed -e 's/^2010/Early/' -e 's/^2013/Development/'`

full line

```
awk -F, '{IGNORECASE=1} {ARGC=1} /\<play\>/{a[$1]++} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' test.txt | sort | sed -e 's/^2010/Early/' -e 's/^2013/Development/'
```

the `^` character tells sed to match only 201X at the start of a line.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This works perfectly fine for the example given above, however with my own files (my bad), it seems to replace any value that contains "2010" with Early, thus some 'Development' columns with "2013" became "Early" instead of 2013. I edited my original post to include this, if you don't mind, please check it out and explain why so.

Comment: sed searches everywhere so it's normal output. with `^` it should do what you want. i've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your reply and clarification, I quite understand this now, sorry for bothering you so much, but just one last thing please, to add this whole output to a new .csv file, I only need to add > tweet.csv correct?

Comment: try it before asking (but that's it yes)